# how to build openssl on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I am trying to build openssl on android (got from https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android). need to make **`.so`** file of this and use in another android project actually. When I try to add all folders of downloaded openssl and build in prompt through ndk-build command, I get an error like this:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'openssl' in workspace/project/apps/Android.mk.

Android NDK: But this module is was already defined by workspace/project/apps/Android.mk.

android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-module.mk:34:
*** Android NDK: Aborting.. Stop.
```

Please let me know how to build .so file!!

Comment: Please publish the contents of `workspace/project/apps/Android.mk`

Answer (score 1):

Please check **Android.mk**, which is the make file for android. I think there is a silly mistake on that file.